# Save a html site state in a link

Tags: html

I am building a character builder website for an upcoming game where you can spend attribute skill points and do other stuff to "theorycraft" a character.

One of the main functionalities should be some way of being able to "save" the character you built to share it with other players.

A very complex example for this would be the official character builder for Path of Exile: https://pathofexile.com/passive-skill-tree

My site is built up pretty simple, showing most information in easy divs and tables. Is there a simple way to do that without using a database?

The use case would look as followed:

1. User A enters site and creates character by altering site (clicking divs and buttons)
2. User A gets link that leads to his created character aka the site with all its local changes made by User A
3. User A can share his new theorycrafted character with User B by sending him the link

Comment: You would want to save the state inside of the url and then parse that URL when the page loads.

Comment: So for example when you click the buttons to 'level up' your skills the url would reflect as such - theorycraft.com/SkillA-1_SkillB-3 etc

Comment: I had a similar idea, but what would I need to do for that?